# Sort a list of lists with multiple keys and unknown ascend/descend

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I'm trying to write code that can sort a list of lists by an unknown number of keys, with each key having an associated boolean corresponding to whether the sort should be ascending or descending.

I have it working to sort by all keys in ascending or descending order like this:

```
import operator

def sort2D(table, *params):
    table.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(*params), reverse = True) 
    return table

table = sort2D(table, *listOfKeys)
```

I'm not sure how to input the boolean values into that function as well though. I get a syntax error when I try to do similar code for a second list of inputs, like this:

```
import operator

def sort2D(table, *params, *args):     #this is the line that causes the syntax error
    table.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(*params), reverse = *args) 
    return table

table = sort2D(table, *listOfKeys, *listOfBools)
```

I can tell that the error is because I'm misusing *, *params, and *args to input a list into the function, but I don't know how I could input the second list without something that looks similar to that. Is it possible to input the second list into the function that I have, or do I have to do something completely different to accomplish what I want?

edit: An example of my desired input and output would look something like this:

```
['Smith', 'Bob', 4, 3.75, 'Blue']
['Jones', 'Tom', 17, 0.44, 'Blue']
['Smith', 'John', 3, 2.22, 'Yellow']
['Jones', 'Drew', 5, 6.74, 'Red']
```

If it were sorted by last name descending and then by integer ascending, then params would be [0, 2] corresponding to the columns and bools would be [True, False]. The output would look like this:

```
['Smith', 'John', 3, 2.22, 'Yellow']
['Smith', 'Bob', 4, 3.75, 'Blue']
['Jones', 'Drew', 5, 6.74, 'Red']
['Jones', 'Tom', 17, 0.44, 'Blue']
```

Comment: You don't need to use argument packing (`*`) to pass a list to a function.

Comment: It would help if you gave a small concrete example of your desired input and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have **two** `*something` parameters to a single function.  Nor can you apply multiple `reverse=` values to a single `sort` call, anyway.

The only clean, completely general way to use multiple `reverse` values (without knowing whether the keys potentially being reversed are strings, numbers, tuples, ...), is, unfortunately, to do multiple `sort` passes (in reverse: the most significant key must be the one on which you sort last).

So...:

```
def sort2D(table, params, reverses):
    for parm, rev in reversed(zip(params, reverses)):
        table.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(parm), reverse=rev) 
    return table

table = sort2D(table, listOfKeys, listOfBools)
```

If you *do* know something about the keys (items) you're sorting on, e.g that they're all numbers, you *could* prepare a single `key` function to then do a single-pass sort (changing sign to numbers corresponding to a true value for the corresponding reversal bool).

But it's a really challenging problem for general keys -- I can't even think of a way to do it effectively for tuples, for example!-)

And even doing it just for strings would I believe be at least a Google-interview-level question -- "define a function `rev` such that, for **any** two strings `s1` and `s2`,

```
rev(s1) < rev(s2) if and only if s1 > s2
```

"""

(Actually in this totally general formulation it's harder than I thought when I was jotting it down...!-)

In real life, faced with such a difficult problem, I'd do the multiple `sort` passes, decree victory, and go home:-)